# Auto-forwarding messages on a Facebook group to a mailing list

Tags: facebook, email-forwarding, automation, mailing-list

A group I'm a member of has people who use email only, Facebook only, and both email and Facebook. I would like to enable to the email-only people to read messages that people post on the group's central column (is that the 'wall'? I dunno, I'm from the email side of things). Specifically, I would like to have some mechanism in place which, as such posts are made, sends them out as email messages to the list address.

This kind of message forwarding is obviously possible in theory, but is there a software package/utility/script/Facebook app/addon which does this already?

Bonus question: Avoid sending the message if the "same" message was already sent to the list.

Answer (score 2):

- Create a Gmail account, and a Facebook account for it.
- Join the Facebook group with it.
- Configure it to receive all email notifications from the Facebook group.
- Create a Gmail filter that forwards to the mailing list all emails from the Facebook address that sends email notifications (e.g.,    `notification+zj4zg6a944oc@facebookmail.com`).

If you use Google Groups for the mailing list then in order to verify the Google Groups' address for auto-forwarding, you'll have to temporarily configure Google Groups so that the public can post to it.

The only problem with this solution is that Facebook currently only sends email notifications of comments on posts if you've commented on the post or if you're tagged in it, so unless you comment on a post (Facebook allows you to do this through email), the mailing list won't receive forwarded notifications of any other comments on that post.

Comment: I don't comment on any post, nor would this auxiliary account. So... I guess you're telling me this won't work? :-(

Comment: It works so long as there's a moderator to post a (possibly canned) response (possibly using using gmail lab's canned responses feature) to every facebook post, or if all facebook group users are asked to only post and not to comment, or if you guys don't care about receiving facebook comments via email.

Comment: Well, I guess I'll try it.